# Testing arguments with toBeCalledWith() in Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have function that uses `puppetteer`'s `page` object to evaluate and return some data.

I would like to write a unit test with `jest` to check if `page.evaluate()` takes specified parameters

This is the function

```
async function cinemasfromState(page, state) {
  const CINEMA_SELECTOR = `div[data-state=$[STATE]] div.top-select-option a.eccheckbox`;
  let res = await page.evaluate(
    (elementPath, state) => {
      let results = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(elementPath)).map(
        function(cin, index) {
          return {
            //Stuff
          };
          return result;
        },
        { state }
      );
    },
    CINEMA_SELECTOR.replace("$[STATE]", state),
    state
  );

  return res;
}
```

Below is what my test looks like

```
describe("cinemasfromState", () => {
  let page_mock = {
    click: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
    evaluate: jest.fn((selector, state) => Promise.resolve())
  };

  test("page.evaluate called correctly ", async () => {
    await cinemasfromState(page_mock, "KAN");
    expect(page_mock.evaluate).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(
      page_mock.evaluate)toBeCalledWith(
        "div[data-state=KAN] div.top-select-option a.eccheckbox",
        "KAN"
      );
  });
});
```

And I get the below error as my test output

```
● cinemasfromState › page.evaluate called correctly

    expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalledWith(expected)

    Expected mock function to have been called with:
      "div[data-state=KAN] div.top-select-option a.eccheckbox"
    as argument 1, but it was called with
      [Function anonymous].

    Difference:

      Comparing two different types of values. Expected string but received function.
      "KAN"
    as argument 2, but it was called with
      "div[data-state=KAN] div.top-select-option a.eccheckbox".
      undefined
    as argument 3, but it was called with
      "KAN".

    Difference:

      Comparing two different types of values. Expected undefined but received string.

      52 |     expect(page_mock1.evaluate).toBeCalledTimes(1);
      53 |     expect(page_mock1.evaluate).toBeCalledWith(
    > 54 |       "div[data-state=KAN] div.top-select-option a.eccheckbox",
         |                            ^
      55 |       "KAN"
      56 |     );
      57 |   });
```

Any help on writing test to verify the arguments?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you read your error log, you'll notice it's trying to match three arguments, but you are only asserting against two. `.toBeCalledWith` in jest will perform an exact match of the arguments passed to the function along with their order.

For instance, if you call `func(arg1, arg2)`, then `expect(func).toBeCalledWith(arg2)` will fail because you did not also assert on `arg1`. This is what is happening in your case because the first argument to `page.evaluate()` is actually an anonymous function.

So, your test will need to be something like this:

```
expect(page_mock.evaluate).toBeCalledWith(
  expect.any(Function),
  "div[data-state=KAN] div.top-select-option a.eccheckbox",
  "KAN"
);
```

Comment: Got it.. 

Is there a reason 
`expect(page_mock.evaluate).toBeCalledWith(
 (arg1, arg2) => {},
  "div[data-state=KAN] div.top-select-option a.eccheckbox",
  "KAN"
);`

wouldn't work